# android switch thumb text cutoff

Tags: android, android-studio, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, android-switch

I wanted to implement an Switch widget in my app and the function works perfectly. The issue I have with the switch is the off text ("OFF") on the thumb. "OFF" is bigger than the size of the thumb. I want to increase the size of the thumb (or decrease the thumb text), but for some odd reason I am unable to do either. Here is what is looks like:

Close up of the switch

[image]

Screen Shot

[image]

Here's the XML file:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/gameSettingsContainer"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.vb1115.multchoicequestion.LaunchScreen">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lessonModeSliderContainer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/lessonModeToggleSlider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:showText="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/lessonModeAnimatedArrow"
        android:src="@mipmap/green_arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/lessonModeSliderContainer"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't think there is an issue from the code itself. All I am doing in my Activity code is finding the Switch view to modify the setOnCheckedChangeListener method.

Comment: check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364153/cant-change-the-textsize-of-the-thumb-of-switchcompat-widget/36418921#36418921

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `android:textSize` on your `Switch` tag like this :

```
    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/lessonModeToggleSlider"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="text_size_here" <----- this line
        android:showText="true"/>
```

The `Switch` class extends `CompoundButton`, which extends `Button`, which extends `TextView`, making this possible. You can also try using `setTextSize()` method on your code to set the text size programatically.

Comment: I tried the following:

XML:
android:textSize="2.0sp"
android:textSize="2dp"
Code:
lessonModeToggle.setTextSize(2.0f);

None of the 3 worked...