# can't change the textsize of the thumb of SwitchCompat widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am having a hard time to change the text size of a switch compact thumb.

Here's my layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
    android:id="@+id/switch_compat2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:checked="true"
    android:switchTextAppearance="@style/MyStyle"
    android:text="SwitchCompat (SDK v7+)"
    app:showText="true" />
```

and the style:

```
<style name="MyStyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#229922</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
</style>
```

yet, no matter what I do on "MyStyle", the switch always look like this:

[image]

Ideally I want have it look like this:

[image]

Anyone would be willing to share their drawables to I can try to match the image above?

I am looking into these threads but not matching properly. It is making it look worse.

[How to change the size of a Switch Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173590/how-to-change-the-size-of-a-switch-widget)

thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually you need to use

```
app:switchTextAppearance="@style/MyStyle"
```

Result:

[image]